# CSV File outputs a new line at the end of the file, despite no new line?

Tags: python, list, csv, file

```
1576,4,7894,False,But you are beautiful.
1577,9,7903,False,I was hoping this would be a happy ending.
1578,5,7908,False,"God bless us, every one."
1579,3,7911,False,C’mon ya all.
1580,19,7930,False,"Then I saw her face, ha ha, now I’m a believer, Not a trace of doubt in my mind,"
1581,4,7934,False,"I’m in love, oh-ah"
1582,10,7944,False,"I’m a believer, I couldn’t leave her if I tried."
```

In the above statement, it outputs a newline from the CSV file. Is this by default? If so, how do I change it? This is my code:

```
    result = []
    for x in range(len(line_text)):
        result.append([line_num[x], num_words[x], total_words[x], is_present[x], line_text[x]])
    with open(f'{output_file}.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csvwriter.writerows(result)
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong as the length of the CSV file should only be 1000, however, it outputs 1001. I would really prefer not to use pandas for just this thing.

Comment: "it outputs 1001" how do you see this? Do you mean it outputs 1,001 records, or just that the text file has a 1,000 records, but an empty last line? What is the value of `len(line_text)`?

Comment: @Grismar The length of line_text is 1000. I'm outputting the length of the CSV file itself, which outputs 1001. Line_text only accounts for the length of how many lines there are in the list itself.

Comment: You say "I'm outputting the length of the CSV file itself" - but the code doesn't show that. My question was how exactly do you determine that the length is 1,001? Have you tried with a smaller number, because that'll make seeing what the problem is a lot easier. Since you provided code that we cannot run, we cannot check for you.

Comment: The last line in your file (if created correctly) will be an empty string `""`. Putting an `if line_text[x]:` before your `append` will skip adding that empty line and give you the same length you expect. Also, is it 1001 records or 1001 lines? Coz it could be 1000 records with 1 header line so 1001 lines is correct, optionally with the 1002nd line being an empty string `""`. Anyway, use a smaller file as a test where you can manually count lines, like 5 lines or 5 records and then compare your expected vs actual.